# Auto adjust Height of the div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I succeeded in implementing auto adjust the `width` of the `div` related to the `device-width`, but I didn't succeed in implementing auto adjust the `height` of the `div` related to the `device-height`.

Actually, I have **4 `buttons`**, some of them are **not visible** when device `height` is **small**.

```css
<!-- BODY {
  background: none transparent;
}

-->.btn {
  position: relative;
  border: 0 !important;
  &:focus {
    outline: 0;
  }
  &:hover {
    top: 2px;
  }
  &:active {
    top: 6px;
  }
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-weight: bold !important;
  max-width: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  .border-radius(10);
  .transition(all, 50ms, ease);
  .btn(rgb(204, 204, 204), 20%);
}

.btn(@color, @percent: 10%) {
  border: 0;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px darken(@color, @percent);
  background-color: @color;
  .box-shadow(0px, 6px, 0px, darken(@color, @percent));
  &:hover {
    border: 0;
    background-color: lighten(@color, 5%) !important;
    .box-shadow(0px, 4px, 0px, darken(@color, @percent));
  }
  &:active {
    .box-shadow(inset, 0px, 3px, 0px, darken(@color, @percent));
  }
}

.position {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="position">
  <button class="btn bg-primary btn-lg">PLAY</button></br>
  </br>
  <button class="btn bg-primary btn-lg">SIGN IN</button></br>
  </br>
  <button class="btn btn-lg bg-primary">SETTINGS</button></br>
  </br>
  <button class="btn bg-primary btn-lg">ABOUT</button></br>
  </br>
</div>
```

**NOTE:** *I want the `div` as `fixed`. (non-scrollable)*

May [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWykt.png) help you for understanding my question better.

Comment: You can add overflow:hidden to the div

Comment: @lilfancy I [tried](https://jsfiddle.net/m6wjq96d/3/), but didn't succeed

Comment: Why are you using @colors and not @media?

Comment: every thing is visible when i tried it out over here, can you add an image ??

Comment: @AlonParag No relations with the question so will look that thing later...

Comment: @lilfancy I have added a line in the last in my question..

Comment: OK I would have a look and get back @Raja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify a height of 100% for `html` and for `body` (supported in old Browsers):

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

or use `vh` instead of `%` (supported in newer Browsers):

```
.position {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20vh;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 80vh;
  background-color: green;
}
```

Note I changed the height from `100%` to `80vh` because that's all you need, if the top position is set to 20vh.

### Explanation:

The %-unit is meant to be relative to the parent element. In your case the `html` and `body` elements are the parents of your `div.position` element. But these elements don't have a height of 100% per default. They only have a width of 100% per default. This is why `width: 100%` works for you, but not `height: 100%`. By setting the height to 100% on these elements you should get your desired result.

The vieport width `vw` and viewport height `vh` units supported in newer browsers are meant bo be relative to the viewport (which basically is the browser window). So `100vh` means: Use 100% of the viewport height. No adjustment to the html and body elements is necessary in that case.

For more information on CSS Units see: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_units.asp

**Edit:**

To achieve the effect of buttons adjusting to the browser height the following adjustments are necessary:

```
...

.position {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20vh;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 80vh;
  background-color: green;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 2vh;
}

.btn-container {
  height: 18vh;
  padding: 2vh;
}

.btn.btn-lg {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 14vh;
  font-size: 8vh;
}
```

and

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="position">
  <div class="btn-container">
    <button class="btn bg-primary btn-lg">PLAY</button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-container">
    <button class="btn bg-primary btn-lg">SIGN IN</button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-container">
    <button class="btn btn-lg bg-primary">SETTINGS</button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-container">
    <button class="btn bg-primary btn-lg">ABOUT</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I [tried](https://jsfiddle.net/m6wjq96d/8/), but then it scrolls when height is small, There is a **Note** in the question...

Comment: Do you mean you get scroll bars, because actually it shouldn't scroll. I also saw you used overflow:hidden. This also should prevent scrolling. Which browser do you use?

Comment: I am using chrome

Comment: Actually, I need that all the contents of div (here, all buttons) shoud adjust themselve according to the height of the browser

Comment: Or do you mean, the gap at the top gets smaller, when the viewport height gets smaller. To prevent this, you would have to use a unit for absolute length for example `top: 5em` and `height: calc(100vh - 5em)` or something similar.

Comment: Ah, I see, you want the buttons to adjust to the viewport height. And you don't want the buttons to be cut off at the bottom, is that right?

Comment: OK, that's actually another question an more complicated to do, but I made some changes to the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ra3Lsckd/9/

Basically what you need to do is, use vh units on the buttons too, and make some adjustments to padding, margin and do some layout stuff with divs.

Comment: I made changes to the answer now to reflect the changes we were talking about and to make it easier for others to see what the final result was.